# How to get organization for Artifacts in UpdateReport?

Tags: sbt

In my SBT plugin I am able to obtain instances of [sbt.Artifact](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/api/index.html#sbt.Artifact) via `UpdateReport`, this comes with a `File`.

However, for `jar`s, I need the `organization` that the jar belongs to. This is available in [sbt.ModuleID](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/api/index.html#sbt.ModuleID).

How do I get the organization when I have the `Artifact`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're getting the aritfact from the update report, you should also be able to get the module id.  The update report is a nested structure, lining up with your Ivy Configurations.  Inside each configuration is a set of Modules, and inside each of those is the set of Artifacts included by that Module (Modules can have more than one artifact, a difference from Maven/Aether).

So, here's example code to grab ALL artifacts form ALL configurations and their ModuleID:

```
for {
   conf <- update.value.configurations
   moduleReport <- conf.modules
   (artifact, file) <-  moduleReport.artifacts
} yield (moduleReport.module, artifact, file)
```

Comment: dagnammit, yes, that was obvious. The `module` was right there on the `moduleReport`